# dotnet file upload with ABP Blob store and Aws S3

Tags: amazon-s3, .net-core, file-upload, abp, blobstorage

I have a question about ABP blob store and Aws S3

I would like to know how to specify the path to save the file, by default it saves it inside a "host" folder. I wish I could change it.

I tried renaming the file $"/newPath/{filename}", but it didn't work for me.

I have followed the following posts

https://blog.antosubash.com/posts/dotnet-file-upload-with-abp

https://community.abp.io/posts/file-uploaddownload-with-blob-storage-system-in-asp.net-core-abp-framework-d01cbe12

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Blob-Storing

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Blob-Storing-Aws

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/d180013a74be092f5bd1abc18f42205a16afa82d/framework/src/Volo.Abp.BlobStoring.Aws/Volo/Abp/BlobStoring/Aws/DefaultAwsBlobNameCalculator.cs#L17 take a look here

it seems like the AWS provider does not support what the filesystem provider supports. which looks like this https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/d180013a74be092f5bd1abc18f42205a16afa82d/framework/src/Volo.Abp.BlobStoring.FileSystem/Volo/Abp/BlobStoring/FileSystem/DefaultBlobFilePathCalculator.cs#L16

so the answer is to create a custom provider using this https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Blob-Storing-Custom-Provider and modify it. use can reuse most of the stuff from here https://github.com/abpframework/abp/tree/d180013a74be092f5bd1abc18f42205a16afa82d/framework/src/Volo.Abp.BlobStoring.Aws/Volo/Abp/BlobStoring/Aws hope this helps